# How do I set up auto refresh for a mapped FTP folder?

Tags: script, ftp

I'm using [FTPUSE](http://www.ferrobackup.com/map-ftp-as-disk.html) to map a FTP drive to a letter in file explorer (unfortunately I have to do this).

My question is, how can I get this mapped FTP dive to auto update (I don't mind polling) to check for new files?
Workflow.

My work flow is I have 2 VM's one hosting(VM1) the FTP server, one accessing it(VM2). Currently if a new file is added to the FTP server (VM1) this does not automatically reflect in (VM2) as expected for FTP, although I would like a way for (VM2) to auto update / fresh to show this new file.

---

PS.
As it's a server I don't mind If runnign a script if there is one to do so although I could not find one personally ( I think mainly as I'm not sure what to google!)

---

Edit.

Just encase it is suggested I did try Expan drive although that marks it as a network drive instead of the mounted drive I need such as in the picture below.
[image]

Comment: So when you map this you have to unmap it and the remap it again?

Comment: When you say **how can I get this mapped FTP dive to auto update (I don't mind polling) to check for new files?** are you needing to automate keeping the drive mapped or to just do something when new files are available in this location? When files are available for download, are you removing the files once they are downloaded as well? What is your current process so help put your question into context a bit more?

Comment: Hi @PIMP_JUICE_IT I've updated the question with the workflow thanks for pointing out I should have added that!.

Comment: So you're saying that when a file is added on the server FTP mailbox, the drive mapping (on the client) to this location does not see the new file when that occurs? If that's the case, when a file is added and F5 is pressed, does the file then show up through the mapped drive?